# How to check Internet Connection in Android for wifi connectivity?

Tags: android

when wifi is connected to wireless modem internet coverage is there or not it always says yes you are conected it only checks wifi conectivity not internet connectivity so how to handle such a situation ?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=10&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Android+for+wifi+connectivity%3F#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=Android+check+wifi+connectivity&oq=Android+check+wifi+connectivity&aq=f&aqi=g-K1&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0i30.31085.31085.1.31327.1.1.0.0.0.0.159.159.0j1.1.0...0.0.8stxRn6JXm8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=fae6a023b37a6159&biw=1280&bih=923.

Comment: Just try to connect to a well known site, e.g. stackoverflow.com - if connection succeeds, then you have internet connectivity.

Comment: @AleksG If I try to connect then the activity is hanged till we get the connection....Deadlock situation occurs

Comment: You can try setting a socket timeout before attempting the connection.  If you set the timeout to 3 second, then it'll try to connect for 3 seconds, then return a failure if unsuccessful.

Comment: @AleksG: Sometimes Even network connection is there and it is slow,In this scenario,Timeout may happen and return the failure message,right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.)u can check it as

```
URL url = new URL("YOUR urlString");
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
.
.
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
//if responseCode = 200 - THEn CONN is connected
```

OR

2.) u can do somethin like dis

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Activity activity) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;  //<--  --  -- Connected
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;  //<--  --  -- NOT Connected
    }
```

Comment: Chintan : I tried the second method.Eventhough I disconnected the wifi ,it shows connected in the network info. I don't know what to do?

Comment: first one is best method (y)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection(Context context)
    {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo)
        {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            {
                if (ni.isConnected())
                {
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
                    Log.v("WIFI CONNECTION ", "AVAILABLE");
                } else
                {
                    Log.v("WIFI CONNECTION ", "NOT AVAILABLE");
                }
            }
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            {
                if (ni.isConnected())
                {
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
                    Log.v("MOBILE INTERNET CONNECTION ", "AVAILABLE");
                } else
                {
                    Log.v("MOBILE INTERNET CONNECTION ", "NOT AVAILABLE");
                }
            }
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code

```
final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

final Network network = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
final NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager
            .getNetworkCapabilities(network);

return capabilities != null
                && capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnected()

The description says:

> Indicates whether network connectivity exists and it is possible to establish connections and pass data.

Answer (score 0):

Right, if you use ConnectivityManager only give information of the connection (WiFi, mobile, WiMax, etc) and if it is connected or not.

To ensure that a data connection you can make a ping:

```
public static boolean ping() {

    try {
        SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("www.example.com", 80); // Set IP/Host and Port
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        //Connect socket to address, and set a time-out to 5 sec
        socket.connect(addr, 5000);
        //If network isn't conecctet then throw a IOException else socket is connected successfully
        socket.close();
        return true;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this to check Internet Connection in Android for wifi Or Mobile Data connectivity

```
 public boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean NisConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
        if (NisConnected) {
            //  if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE || activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
           return true;
            } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also just like this

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context)
{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```